# How to show two level of X-Axis in ms-Chart

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, mschart

I have a report that show some info about cities.I want to show the state name below all cities along with a state.

such this image:

[image]

how I can do  this similar to image (not Exactly) with ms chart ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add 2 rows of CustomLabels, e.g.:

```
private void FillChart()
{
    // fill the data table with values
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("State", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Population", typeof(int));

    dt.Rows.Add(0, "City1", "State1", 100);
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "City2", "State1", 30);
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "City3", "State1", 40);
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "City1", "State2", 80);
    dt.Rows.Add(4, "City2", "State2", 70);

    // bind the data table to chart
    this.chart1.Series.Clear();

    var series = this.chart1.Series.Add("Series 1");
    series.XValueMember = "Id";
    series.YValueMembers = "Population";

    series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
    this.chart1.DataSource = dt;
    this.chart1.DataBind();

    // custom labels 
    foreach (var g in dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("State")))
    {
        string state = g.Key;
        var cities = g.Select(r => new { Id = r.Field<int>("Id"), City = r.Field<string>("City") });
        // find min-max
        int min = cities.Min(y => y.Id);
        int max = cities.Max(y => y.Id);
        // city labels
        foreach (var city in cities)
        {
            var label = new CustomLabel(city.Id - 1, city.Id + 1, city.City, 0, LabelMarkStyle.None);
            this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(label);
        }
        // city states
        var statelabel = new CustomLabel(min, max, state, 1, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark);
        this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(statelabel);
    }
}
```

Result is pretty similar:

[image: Chart with 2 rows of labels]

Answer (score 1):

In Visual studio RDLC this can be easily achieved by

1. create a dataset and add a datatable with fields; city,state,value
   [image: see image]
2. create a blank RDLC report and insert a chart of your choice from the tool box selecting your datatable as the datasource
3. click on the  chart area to get "Chart data" dialog
4. For Vlues add "your value", for category groups add "State" and "City"
   [image: see image]